# AutoIt and RSelenium to navigate Save As dialogue (Firefox)

Tags: r, firefox, autoit, rselenium

I have been trying now for days (if not weeks...) to get the code below to work. What I am trying to achieve is that an R script runs daily (via batch script and Windows Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2008 64bit).
That R script shall navigate to certain websites, log in and invoke the Save As dialogue to save complete pages to a specific path.

If I run my script on my machine (Win 8 - 64bit) within RStudio it works like a charme - remotely and via Rscript.exe it does not.

The problem appears to be with the SaveAs.au3 script - when I call it via RStudio or from file explorer it works perfectly. The same R Script executed within a batch file with:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\JN\abc.R"
```

works up until the system() command as well and crahses then without providing any error or warning.

Maybe there is someone who had a similar problem and can help? Thanks!

**The 3 AutoIt scripts are the following:**

*SaveAs.au3 / exe*

```
ControlFocus("[CLASS:MozillaWindowClass]", "", "")
ControlSend("[CLASS:MozillaWindowClass]", "", "", "^s")
```

*EditName.au3* will be variably written from within R and then called

*KeyEnter.aut3*

```
ControlFocus("Save as", "", "")
ControlClick("Save as","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
```

**The R script looks as follows:**

```
# compl is a vector of n href 

if(length(compl) != 0) {
  foreach(i=1:length(compl)) %do% {
    server_check() # checks whether selenium driver is still active and firefox window is open
    remDr$navigate(compl[i])
    Sys.sleep(10)
    login_check() # checks whether login is still active
    Sys.sleep(5)
    print(paste("attempt to save:",compl[i]))
    system('C:\\JN\\SaveAs.exe') # does not matter whether .exe or .au3
    Sys.sleep(3)
    system("cmd", input = c('echo ControlSetText("Save as", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "") > C:\\JN\\EditName.au3',
                            paste0('echo ControlSend("Save as", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "',
                                   gsub("/","_",gsub(website_url,"", compl[i])), ".htm",
                                   '") >> C:\\JN\\EditName.au3')))
    Sys.sleep(3)
    system('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\AutoIt3\\AutoIt3.exe C:\\JN\\EditName.au3')
    Sys.sleep(8)
    system('C:\\"Program Files (x86)"\\AutoIt3\\AutoIt3.exe C:\\JN\\KeyEnter.au3')
    Sys.sleep(30)
  }
}
print("Complete save end")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to Windows Server 2008 R2 - if you disconnect from the remote session the server will initiate a screen server (or alike) making the AutoIt script unable to interact with the GUI (as there is non...)

There are options within Windows Server to prevent the server from disabling the GUI, but my script was still not stable enough to run on its own for months...